# Firewalld ssh secure

Tags: centos, firewalld

How can I add two rules to firewalld in order to

1. deny everyone and
2. accept only set of several IP addresses?

In this here case I am talking about SSH port - 22.
I am using CentOS 7 and firewalld.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=public --add-rich-rule="rule family="ipv4" \
source address="1.2.3.4/32" \
port protocol="tcp" port="22" accept"
```

Just replace the IP with the one you want to allow for ssh

Comment: Thank you and how about the rest ips. Will they automatically be denied without any more rules?

Comment: This depend on your current active zone, and services, see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Check which zone is currently is active and used by default for your connection,

```
# firewall-cmd --get-active-zones 
work
  interfaces: work-vpn
home
  interfaces: enp0s25
```

so for example in the output above I have 2 active zones, one for each interface.

Then you need to list the active service for the specific zone,

```
# firewall-cmd --list-services --zone=public
dhcpv6-client mdns ssh
```

So in the above case the public zone have a rule to allow ssh in. And so if you like to allow access from a spesifc address, you first need to remove the ssh service, and and the rich rule from above which @noqqe mention.

```
# firewall-cmd 
     --permanent        # this will add the rule permanently, su make sure not to run it on a remote host, until you verified it!
     --zone=public      # to which zone add the rule, make sure is the one you actively/currently using.
```